# Doctrine Grouping Rows Into One Row and SUM Quantity Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine query that I am trying to group similar rows and SUM their quantities (qty). It looks like this, but it is not working...

```
public function getProducts($id, $account_id){

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
        SELECT      p, pr, sum(p.qty) as qty
        FROM        WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderProductsStatus p
        JOIN        p.product pr
        WHERE       p.inventoryLocation = :id
        AND         p.account = :account_id
        GROUP BY    p.product')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id);

    try{
        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 Key "product" for array with keys "0, qty" does not exist in my twig template
```

If I remove the ", sum(p.qty) as qty" it works fine, it just does not give me the SUM of the columns I am grouping by.

Here is the loop in my Twig template.

```
 {% for productAction in productActions %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ productAction.product.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ productAction.product.sku }}</td>
                            <td>{{ productAction.product.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ productAction.qty }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Anyone have a clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results

The nature of a result can be of 2 forms: pure and mixed.
By default, the result type is pure but as soon as scalar values, such as aggregate values or other scalar values that do not belong to an entity, appear in the SELECT part of the DQL query, the result becomes mixed.
A mixed result has a different structure than a pure result in order to accommodate for the scalar values.

A pure result usually looks like this:

```
array(
    '0' => obj1,
    '1' => obj2
);
```

A mixed result on the other hand has the following general structure:

```
array(
    '0' => array(
        '0' => Obj1,
        'qty' => your scalar value sum(p.qty)
    ),
    '1' => array(
        '0' => Obj2,
        'qty' => your scalar value sum(p.qty)
    ),
);
```